# separate syllables creating rules

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python. So far I got this:

```
vowels = 'aeiouAEIUO'
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNÑPQRSTVWXYZ'
a = input('Type a word: ')

for i in range(len(a)):
    cont1 = 0
    cont2 = 0
    if a[i] in consonants:
        cont1 = i - 1
        cont2 = i + 1
        if a [cont1] in vowels and a [cont2] in vowels:
                print('consonant between vowels')
```

I want to separate syllables. I want to create a rule that when a consonant is between 2 vowels, the consonant has to join to the vowel on it's right and print the syllables separated by '-'
    montoya = mon-to-ya
    amor = a-mor
    clase = cla-se

This code of course gives an error: IndexError: string index out of range. I don't know what that means.

Thanks

Comment: The rule isn't very good, though.  It doesn't work for e.g. "letra" where there are two consonants between the vowels.

Comment: That would be another rule. There are several rules that I want to apply but I want to start with the consonant between two vowels

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a rule that when a consonant is between 2 vowels, the
>   consonant has to join to the vowel on it's right.

You could use `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> vowels = 'aeiouAEIUO'
>>> consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNÑPQRSTVWXYZ'
>>> pattern="([" + vowels + "])" + "([" + consonants + "]" + "[" + vowels + "])"
>>> re.sub(pattern, r'\1-\2', "amor")
'a-mor'
>>> re.sub(pattern, r'\1-\2', "clase")
'cla-se'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. But, how can I implement this on the code. And also, I tryed: 
>>> re.sub(pattern, r'\1-\2', "alexis")
'a-lexis'

Comment: @user2558831 It isn't quite clear what your question is.  Could you clarify?